# How to disable QPushButton hover default animation

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I create a QPushButton, then add a transparent image as the background.
When i mouse move in the button area, there was such animation effect which look likes the background image was pasted the background again. If mouse hover then move out, and repeat that, the background image color get deeper and deeper. Feel like the background image is pasted again and again.
 I just want no any effect when mouse hover, just simply display the background image whether hover or not.

```
QPushButton *mButton = new QPushButton(this);
QPixmap pixmap(RETURN_BUTTON_PIC);
QString buttonCSS
("
  QPushButton{background: none; background-color: transparent; border:none;} 
  QPushButton:hover{background: none; border:none;}
");
mButton->setStyleSheet(buttonCSS);
mButton->setIcon(QIcon(pixmap));
mButton->setIconSize(pixmap.rect().size());
```

Comment: By the way, I do not wish disable the whole hover event, Thanks in advance

Comment: You may completely customize your button. In this case there will be no animations at all. Try to set border directly. For example: `border: 1px solid transparent;`